# Is there an idiomatic way to exchange two elements in a cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I know that I can write it like this:

```
tmp = arr{i}
arr{i} = arr{j}
arr{j} = tmp
```

But is there a simpler way? For instance, in Python I'd write:

```
arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Standard, idiomatic way**:

Use a vector of indices:

```
arr([i j]) = arr([j i]); %// arr can be any array type
```

This works whether `arr` is a cell array, a numerical array or a string (char array).

---

**Not recommended** (but possible):

If you want to use a syntax more similar to that in Python (with a *list of elements* instead of a vector of indices), you need the [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function. But the resulting statement is more complicated, and varies depending on whether `arr` is a cell array or a standard array. So it's not recommended (for exchanging two elements). I include it only for completeness:

```
[arr{i}, arr{j}] = deal(arr{j}, arr{i}); %// for a cell array
[arr(i), arr(j)] = deal(arr(j), arr(i)); %// for a numeric or char array
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I am looking for. Having no real experience of MATLAB I get insanely confused by all the different types of brackets, when to use them, and so on. Thanks for answering such a simple noob question.

Comment: I have quite some experience in Matlab and get confused also, specially with curly braces. So don't feel discouraged by that :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Here is the mini tutorial: square brackets `[]` for concatenation into an array, round brackets `()` for function calls and accessing elements, and curly brackets `{}` for accessin the *content* of elements (mostly relevant for cell arrays) and concatenation into a cell array.

Answer (score 2):

Not to confuse things, but let me another syntax:

```
[arr{[i,j]}] = arr{[j,i]};
```

or

```
[arr{i},arr{j}] = arr{[j,i]};
```

The idea here is to use [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) with curly-braces indexing.

Remember that when working with cell-arrays, `()`-indexing gives you a [sliced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) cell-array, while `{}`-indexing extracts elements from the cell-array and the return type is whatever was stored in the specified cell (when the index is non-scalar, MATLAB returns each cell content individually as a comma-separated list).

Comment: Good spot, this is an alternative worth mentioning as well